# jQuery - Checkbox checked enables field next to it in table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I currently have a table with a checkbox and product name on one side, then a quantity input field on the other side. By default, the quantity field is disabled, but I would like to enable it only if its corresponding product is checked.

I'm still new to jQuery and a bit stuck on this, so this is a best I could come up with:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
            
            //enable quantity field if product is selected
            $("input[name='quantity']").prop('disabled', 'true');
            $(".product").on('click', function(){
                 $next = $(this).next();
                $next.prop('disable', 'false');
            });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th width="150">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
       <tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='product' class='product' name='product'><label>Product</label></td>
<td><input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity' id='quantity'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='product' class='product' name='product'><label>Product</label></td>
<td><input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity' id='quantity'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' id='product' class='product' name='product'><label>Product</label></td>
<td><input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity' id='quantity'></td>
</tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: I usually have better luck using checkbox pseudo class to subscribe to event changes on checkboxes such as `$(':checkbox').change(function(){...})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have duplicate IDs for input element. IDs must be unique. you can rather use classname and then use class selector to target element by classname.

And your solution is not working because

1) you have wrong selector to target next input element. you need to traverse to closest tr and then find element with name quantity in it.

2) You are setting wrong property. you need to use `disabled` instead of `disable` :

```
$(".product").change(function(){
   $next = $(this).closest('tr').find('[name=quantity]');
   $next.prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/50hoyo3a/)**

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".product").on('change', function(){
             
               $(this).closest('tr').find("input[name='quantity']").prop('disabled',!this.checked);
                           });
```

Answer (score 0):

To get what you want you can use this two DOM traversal methods  `.closest()` or `.parents()`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  //enable quantity field if product is selected
  $("input[name='quantity']").prop('disabled', true);
  $(".product").change(function(){
      $(this)
          .parents('td')
          .next()
          .find('input')
          .prop('disabled', !$(this).is(":checked"));
              
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th width="150">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
       <tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='product' name='product'><label>Product</label></td>
<td><input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity'></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='product' name='product'><label>Product</label></td>
<td><input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity' ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type='checkbox' class='product' name='product'><label>Product</label></td>
<td><input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity' ></td>
</tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: @Mohammad Check now, It's toggled.

Answer (score 0):

First, fix your code so that you don't have duplicate IDs. It won't prevent the code from running, but it's not good HTML.

Here's how I would write the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // Enable quantity field if product is selected
    $("input[name='quantity']").prop('disabled', true);

    $(".product").on('click', function() {
        // Get reference to the text field in the same row with the name "quantity"
        var $next = $(this).closest('tr').find('input:text[name="quantity"]');

        // Enable the text field if the checkbox is checked, disable it if it is unchecked
        $next.prop('disabled', ! $(this).is(':checked'));
    });
 });
```

That will enable AND disable it as required.

Answer (score 0):

This approach does what you are looking for.

```js
$(function(){
  $(':checkbox').change(function(){
     var prodId = $(this).data('productidckbx');
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $('#prodquantity-' + prodId).prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
       $('#prodquantity-' + prodId).prop('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.js"></script>
<table id="products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product Name</th>
      <th width="150">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type='checkbox' id='product-1'  name='product' data-productidckbx='1'>
        <label>Product</label>
      </td>
      <td><input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity' id='prodquantity-1'  disabled="disabled"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><input type='checkbox' id='product-2' class='product' name='product' data-productidckbx='2'>
    <label>Product</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity' id='prodquantity-2' disabled="disabled"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
    <input type='checkbox' id='product-3' class='product' name='product' data-productidckbx='3'>
    <label>Product</label>
  </td>
  <td>
    <input type='text' placeholder='0' name='quantity' id='prodquantity-3' disabled="disabled">
  </td>
</tr>
       </tbody>
      </table>
```

Comment: To expand on my above post, I'm suggesting the use of data attributes to store and id that you can use to build the appropriate query selector for the input text field paired with its corresponding checkbox